How to find clusters in BERT embedding space that align with specific meaning?
I do not know if this is do-able, or a very hard task.
Imagine I have 100 million sentences and paragraphs of people saying that some treatment helped some condition. I use BERT to make embeddings for each of these sentences.
Now the goal is to look at a map (literally or figuratively using algorithms) of a space made from the original embedding space and be able to see clusters or hotspots of many sentences that talk about the same condition. Or if the next day I want to look at hotspots that talk about the same treatment, I could distill the original embedding space into a different space that does that for me.
Similar clusters should be nearer together than more different treatments. For example if there are 10 sentences about Advil, 10 about Tylenol, and 10 about chemotherapy, the hotspots for Advil and Tylenol should be close together (but not on top of each other) and the hotpot for lemon oil should be far away.
Example sentences:

"Tylenol cured my gout."

"Tylenol helped fix my back pain."

"Tylenol treated my headaches."

"Advil cured my gout."

"Advil helped fix my back pain."

"Advil treated my headaches."

"Lemon oil cured my gout."

"Lemon oil helped fix my back pain."

"Lemon oil treated my headaches."


I would like to be able to use the embeddings BERT made of these 9 sentences, and somehow project them onto a "treatment space" where 1, 2, and 3 are practically on top of each other. The group of 4, 5, and 6 is near the first group. And the group of 7, 8, and 9 is far away.
And then using these same original embeddings, I would like to look at these sentences in "condition space", where 1, 4, and 7 create a hotspot for sentences talking about gout, 2, 5, and 8 create a hotspot for back pain, and 3, 6, and 9 create a hotspot for headaches.
My only idea so far is generating embeddings from labeled sentences, for example imagine those example sentences were the labeled ones and not the massive dataset of unlabeled sentences. 1, 2, and 3 are labeled "Tylenol" and so on.
To get optimal directions for treatment clustering, I would get embeddings of the labeled sentences, and then use some method to find directions that separate different labels and cluster similar labels most effectively. These would be the treatment dimensions that I could project the original embeddings onto to separate by treatment.
Similarly, I would generate directions for conditions by using different labels for the sentences based on conditions.
The problem with the above approach, I think, is that it will be encouraged to separate them all as far from each other as possible. So Tylenol and Advil might become just as far from each other as Tylenol and lemon oil. But I want to them to be near each other, kind of like the analgesic area of the map.
This ideally shouldn't require complex labeling and training to get the new directions. The original BERT model should already have a sense that Tylenol and Advil are more similar to each other than to lemon oil, and they should be nearer together in some directions in the embedding. I'm wondering if there's a way to zero in on that knowledge in the embedding space and ignore all else, so that all Tylenol sentences are in the same place.
Is anything like this possible?
